# Memory Leak on Linux device

Tags: linux, memory, memory-leaks

Problem here is memory leak seen after downloading image on to the device.

Downloading procedure

1. Create tempfs and first download the image on to tempfs
2. Validate the image
3. Write the image to flash
4. Free all buffers created and unmount tmpfs

But I see memory leak equals to image size. That memory is added to cached section. This is confirmed by looking at the dump of "free" command on Linux(2.6.21.7) terminal.

Comment: being in the cache does not mean it's a memory leak

Comment: See http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add some more details, because it's not clear at all what kind of device are you talking about, what kind of "buffers" are freed.

But trying to guess about the question: whatever is in the "cached" section, it is actually allowed to be reclaimed by any application. The file is still cached in case there is a handle somewhere which can still access the contents. This doesn't prevent anyone from allocating that memory - it will be simply freed when there is no non-cache memory to use anymore.

This saves you from accessing disks when you don't really have to.

Comment: Device is Network switch.switching protocol suit will run on Linux kernel.